# How to check value of tooltip in nightwatch

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I'm writing a test which checks that some text appears when you hover over a link. Currently unable to do this as the DOM doesn't change on hover so there's no element to check. See html below:

```
<span data-qaid="printAndExport">
   <li title="Some hover text"><a href="" class="disabled" data-qaid="printLink" tabindex="-1"><em class="icon icon-print"></em><span class="disabled">Print</span></a></li>
   <li title="Some hover text"><a href="" class="disabled" data-qaid="exportLink" tabindex="-1"><em class="icon icon-get_app"></em><span class="disabled">Export</span></a></li>
</span>
```

I've tried an assertion on the link itself but that obviously doesn't work as that'll just return the link text itself instead of the value on hover. The only thing I can think of is to check the title attribute but that's not directly testing the functionality on the WebApp by hovering, its just checking an attribute in the DOM. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `.moveToElement('[data-qaid="printLink"]')`

Comment: @AlapanDas Yep I'm using moveToElement for the hover action, the issue is when I hover, how to then check the value of the text which appears on hover. Sorry should have been clear about that in my post.

Comment: can you check in the DOM manually when you hover any elements are added or changed with the hover text ?

Comment: @AlapanDas The DOM remains exactly the same when I hover over any elements on the app which have hover text.

Comment: Is your app a public app? If yes then I can look into it, difficult to debug like this.

Comment: @AlapanDas Unfortunately it's not public.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the solution I've decided to go with is the one I was initially avoiding but I can't see a better way to do this.

In order to test this I'm going to get the "title" attribute value and do an assertion on that. This doesn't explicitly test the hover functionality so not 100% happy.

Link to article for solution: https://www.guru99.com/verify-tooltip-selenium-webdriver.html

Answer (score 0):

In some cases when you hover on an element you get a DOM update which is associate with the wanted element and in some cases the element itself is changed due the tooltip being presented(class name changed etc.).

Since in your case there aren't any changes in the DOM and asserting the title does not check the functionally of the tooltip I'm coming up with 2 plausible solutions.

**1.**
You can use screenshots comparison to verify if the tooltip indeed appeared but it will take some work to set it up.

**2.**
Developers don't tend to write their DOM thinking how well it is optimized for automation testing.
In short, open a Jira ticket for example and state that in the moment there isn't a good way to test the element and it needs to be updated in some way or form.

Comment: Actually the first option will be the quickest for me as I already have image compare capabilities in my framework. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I will let you know if there is a better solution